# Что такое "ни", как частица?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Никогда не задумывался в смысле частицы "ни", а если и задумывался, то приходил к выводу, что не понимаю её. В письме она встречается часто, и думаю, что ставил её в правильных местах. Кто-нибудь, help!

Comment: Примеры употребления "ни ..., ни ...".

Не дари мне ни виллу, ни яхту. <=> Не дари мне виллу, и не дари мне яхту.

Иван не любит ни Дарью, ни Марью. <=> Иван не любит Дарью, и Иван не любит Марью.

Comment: Ни Дарья, ни Марья не любят Ивана. <=> Дарья не любит Ивана, и Марья не любит Ивана.

Comment: "Ни" употребляется в предложениях типа "Каковы бы ни были две различные точки, существует единственная прямая, которой обе эти точки принадлежат.".

Answer (score 3):

В качестве отрицательной частицы ни употребляется в следующих случаях: 
1. Для усиления отрицания, которое есть в предложении и которое выражается частицей не или словами нет, нельзя. 
Усиление отрицания (быть «спутником» слов  нет, нельзя) — основная функция частицы ни: «Он никогда не был ни прекрасным, ни хорошим, а был самым обыкновенным учеником» 
Отрицание может подразумеваться: «А на Неве ни шороха, ни плеска».
Употребленная для усиления отрицания при однородных члена предложения, частицами приобретает значение соединительного союза: «Ничто его не интересовало: ни море, ни тропическая растительность, ни горы, ни их характер»
2. Для выражения полного запрета или настойчивой просьбы: «Ни с места!»

Answer (score 1):

У Вас трудности с различением НЕ и НИ ? Частица НИ употребляется 1)для усиление отрицания
(никто не был);
для усиления утвердит. смысла в уступит. придат. предложении (как ни…, кто ни…, когда ни…): Как ни старался, не мог понять.
2)в сочетаниях ни разу (никогда),нимало не (ничуть, нисколько),как ни бывало (было),
ни один (никто),никто иной(другой) не …,как никто иной(другой),ничто иное(другое) не …,
как ничто иное(другое),3) в составе фразеологизмов (ни рыба ни мясо,ни много ни мало, ни то ни сё, откуда ни возьмись,ни туда ни сюда, ни взад ни вперёд, во что бы то ни стало,как ни в чём не бывало, как бы то ни было)
4 ) в отрицат. мест. и наречиях без ударения (никто′ не)

Частица НЕ употребляется для отрицания1)в вопросит. и восклицат.простых  предл. обобщённо-усилит. характера (часто есть частица ТОЛЬКО, УЖ),Кто только его не ругал!но: в знач. «всё равно что»- НИ :Кто это сказал? - А кто бы НИ сказал! 2)не раз (а часто, много раз), немало (много),
как не бывало (не было), не один (а много); не кто иной(другой), как; не что иное(другое), как;3) двойное отрицание = положительный результат(не мог не видеть = должен видеть)4)в отрицат. мест. и наречиях под ударением (не′кто)